# Checkbox in <a href> tag

Tags: javascript, html

This is my HTML code:

```
<a id="id_1" name="n_1" href="#" onclick="callFn(this.id);">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ck_1" id="xyz">
    Click Here
</a>
```

I want to check this checkbox using Javascript code. How to do it??

Comment: Your HTML is invalid. Anchors cannot contain interactive elements, including input elements.

Comment: I suspect the solution to your problem is "use a label element, not an anchor"

Answer (score 1):

Use `<label>` instead of `<a>`.

```
<label id="id_1" onclick="callFn(this.id);">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ck_1" id="xyz">
    Click Here
</labek>
```

This is the use of `<label>` tag. And moreover, you don't need `callFn(this.id);` at all.

Comment: correct html, just doesn't answer the javascript question

Comment: @Gavriel Kindly remove your comment. I will add more info.

Comment: no need, as this is a duplicate question anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. And, I need callFn(this.id) because I am doing some calculations at the back

Comment: @Gavriel if you are going to mark a dup at least pick a relevant one.

Comment: @User2403 Yeah, you can just do that.

Answer (score 0):

Get the element using its ID:`document.getElementById("xyz")`

Then change its property `checked` to true:

`document.getElementById("xyz").checked = true;`

Comment: your answer may be correct, but please add a bit more so beginners can understand what you are coming to. The community wants to help you, and we are trying are best, but we can only understand questions that make sense. Try to format your question a bit differently after you check out StackOverflow's Help Center page on how to write a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xZpqmG)**.. hope it helps

```js
    $("#check").click(function() {
        var checkBoxes = $("#xyz");
        checkBoxes.attr("checked", !checkBoxes.attr("checked"));
    });
```

```html
<label id="id_1" onclick="callFn(this.id);" for="xyz">
    <input type="checkbox" name="ck_1" id="xyz">
    Click Here
</labek>
<br/>
<button id="check">By button</button>
```